# Using a string in click function of windows form app

Tags: c++, windows, string

Just a curious question.

Is it possible to get the editor to allow the use of strings in a click function of a design project?  Say for this function that was created when the click button was created:

```
System::Void Form1::Calculate_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
```

When I try to create a string within the function with the normal approach 'String variable-name', I get this answer:

```
'System::String' : cannot use this type here without a top-level '^'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `System::String^ variable_name` ?

Comment: I have but I wanted to be able to convert the string variables into integers or floats.  I was planning to use atoi to convert the input.

Comment: you can use converters inside `System::ComponentModel` namespace, or you can convert it to `wchar*` like this `pin_ptr<const wchar_t> _wch = PtrToStringChars(net_string)`

Comment: Huh... that's new.  One last question.  Is there a compare function that can handle System::String^ and String, char[] for string comparisons.

Comment: I am not aware of any standard functions that does that, but you could write one yourself like `char CompareTwoStrings(System::String^ s1,wchar_t* s2){System::String^ _pom = gcnew System::String(s2); if(_pom==s1) return 1; return 0; }` and another overload for different parameters position. You could do it the other way around, converting managed to native and then comparing, but I believe that it's a bit slower but safer to convert the native string to .net and than compare it.